# Conditions based on type of a variable in scala

Tags: scala, variables, conditional-statements

I want to handle my if condition based on the type of a variable which is predefined to be Any  type and later it got updated to a type either String, Int, double, List or Map

```
if (type(x)==int){.....}
else if (type(x)==Map){....}
```

and so on

Is there a function to get the type of a variable or how can i get the type of a variable
to use it in if conditions.I know one of the way is to use

```
x.getClass.getSimpleName
```

but when the type of x is a Map 
it prints Map1 or Map2 for different Maps which i am not sure what 1 and 2 denotes here
so i cant use it in the if condition since

```
if (x.getClass.getSimpleName==Map){....}
```

will be false as I dont know Map1 or Map2 will come

Comment: Have a look at the `match` keyword - kind of like a super-charged switch statement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We call this *pattern matching* and it's one of the most awesome scala parts:

```
def foo(x: Any) = x match {
  case m: Map[_,_] => println("I'm a map!")
  case d: Double   => println("I'm a double")
  case i: Int      => println("I'm an int")
  case xs: List[_] => println("I'm a list")
}
```

Underscores denote *any type, i don't care which one*

Comment: The Neophyte's Guide to Scala is an awesome series of blog posts introducing Scala starting with the awesome match statement: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html